# Portable VTOL Startup

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, electric-engine, vtol

I am Alessandro and I am currently developing a new portable electric VTOL that can be carried by car without a trailer and allows a flight time of around 15 min carrying one person.

The expected price will be around 70k.

May I ask you for some feedbacks about this idea?

For example, if you would be more interested in a lower price with reduced flight time, or your potential use case or habits if there are.

Thank you

Comment: Just 15 mins of flight time seems pretty short imo. How do you intend to transport without a trailer?

Comment: I wouldn't bother taking it out of the trunk for 15 minutes of flight.  Much less drop $70k for the privilege.  If i wanted to take an aerial photo of my car I'd buy a small drone.  Sorry to be blunt, but that's my feedback.

Comment: Please don't be disheartened that your question was closed. If possible can you edit it to included a more focused question? Then you can request it to be reopened.

Comment: What kind of VTOL do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: For that price and that short amount of flight is a little bit pricey. I can't think of any mission that short I would do. Only occurs to me something like getting to a beautiful place in your car but there is no more road access and you want to see more of that place and get a nice air view. It would be like having a DJI drone that you can ride. For that I would pay maybe max 50k.

Answer (score 6):

15 minutes is not very long in flying, and that level of endurance would only be acceptable for a motorglider.

You want an hour at minimum, and that still only makes it an amusement device. Electric paramotors just get there, mainly thanks to extremely low wing loadings so little energy is required to sustain flight.

I'll provide an opinion, but based on a fundamental fact.  Electric flight is going nowhere with batteries that can only manage 250-300 Wh/Kg, and can randomly turn into roman candles (Boeing learned this the hard way with the 787's batteries, being forced to design L-ion-fireproof enclosures to get the fleet back in the air).

When a battery comes along, that with motor can match my aircraft engine and fuel supply pound for pound while providing the 4 hours endurance that gas does, while being immune to spontaneous self-discharge, I'll convert my own plane to electric.